# Good practice for string pool in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, string

In Java, we usually create a `StringPool.class` to store frequently used `String`s. For example: we declare

`public static final String SPACE = " ";`and we call `StringPool.SPACE`when needed.

Is it good practice to do this in Ruby as well? If yes, can you give an example of `StringPool`in Ruby?

Comment: Why do you do that in Java? Also, Ruby has :symbols.

Comment: String in java is immutable; if you declare " " twice, then it's a waste of memory because there are 2 " ". So by using a StringPool.class, we only create 1 " " and reuse it.

Comment: I think the Java compiler takes care of such things for you.

Comment: Like Ari said use `:symbols`.

Comment: @justin_beaver Java uses immutable interned strings so it doesn't waste memory. This means that should you declare space (" ") twice, only one actual string instance will be created in the jvm, yet you will have two references pointing on it.

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this and is wondering. There is no need to create a StringPool.class and a use StringPool.SPACE in Java as described above. As mentioned Java Strings are immutable and one big reason they are immutable is that Java uses a string pool internally so no matter if you declare " " twenty times, there will only ever be one " " created.  All variables will hold a reference to the same " ". This is why strings are immutable, if one reference changes its string all others still point to the original. You do not have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to **group** a set of constants in ruby within a specific context, you could do this using a class or a module like so:

```
class MyConstants
  CONST_1 = "Constant1"
  CONST_2 = "Constant2"
  # ...
end
```

or

```
module MyConstants
  CONST_1 = "Constant1"
  CONST_2 = "Constant2"
end
```

You could then access those constants in the following way:

```
MyConstants::CONST
```

Note that constant values can be anything besides strings, even symbols. As previously mentioned in other answers, it is a common idiom in ruby to use symbols. However, this pattern makes sense when you want to make explicit the fact that your constants belong to a certain context (i.e. like an enumeration). This enforces IMHO the semantics of your application.

Comment: Yes, this is what i intended to do. Also i agree with u on enforcing the semantics. Thanks.

Comment: This can be good for semantic purposes (though symbols might be better still) but I want to emphasize that this should **not** be used for optimization in Ruby. A "string pool" as it exists in Java has no equivalent in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was already provided by **Ari** in comments, but I will duplicate it here to help others find answers fast.

You need a symbol.

#### What is a symbol?

[Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html) is immutable, fast to compare string.

#### How to make a symbol?

You can define its instances these ways:

```
:foo # => :foo <- it's a symbol
"string".to_sym # => :string <- symbol too. But prefer a first way 
                # due to avoid string object creation.
```

#### It mustn't be magic!

And it is not. All symbols are stored in special `symbol-table` even your `:foo` and `:string`. You can look into symbols table:

```
Symbol.all_symbols #=> [:execute_script, :array_new_range, :ExtendCommand, ...]
```

This table seems to be really big. What if you want to find symbol in it?

```
Symbol.all_symbols.index(:foobar42) # => bad. It will find index of symbol 
                                    # :foobar42 but it will create it first 
                                    # if it wasn't.
Symbol.all_symbols.index(/foobar42/) # returns nil if there's no such a symbol
```

The symbols are fast to compare because they are immutable. Method `==` just checks if object_ids are same.

#### When to use symbols?

I'm pretty sure you know. When you want to use one string couple of times and not planning to change it.

*That's all.*

My first thought after reading your question was: hey, why do they need string pools? I thought strings are immutable in java. That's why we have to use string builders and other stuff. But then I saw `public static final String`. Oh yeah, it is *java*.